# Are there computational tools to extract features of DNA sequences?

Tags: python, phylogenetics, features

I am looking for tools to extract features from short DNA sequences. For example, entropy, complexity, GC-content, etc.

I have found the [generateFeatures.py](https://github.com/mrzResearchArena/PyFeat/blob/master/Codes/generateFeatures.py) script from the [PyFeat](https://github.com/mrzResearchArena/PyFeat/) repo, but is there love a more widely used source code or a standard way to extract features from sequences biopython or similar?

Also, I think that since there are $2N$ encoded bits in a sequence of $N$ nucleotides, we have **at most** $2N$ independent features that could be extracted.

---

In addition, I am curios if there are any [transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) models for DNA sequences.

---

***Edit***:
In addition, you can use [DeepHF's feature utils](https://github.com/crispr-il/DeepHF/blob/d05444e6fa209e734dabc8defc853585afdffe5b/DeepHF/scripts/feature_util.py), which can be accessed and consumed as seen [here](https://github.com/crispr-il/DeepHF/blob/d05444e6fa209e734dabc8defc853585afdffe5b/DeepHF/scripts/preprocess.py#L133).

Comment: Great question! +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with biopython, the [SeqUtils](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.SeqUtils.html) package could be a solution.